# Select from table with dynamic compute name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write query in which name table will dynamicaly compute. I have code like this below. What should I put in 'magic code' region?

```
DECLARE @myTableName nvarchar(100) = 'sch' 
         +  CAST(@nowYear as VARCHAR(5)) 
         +  'Q' 
         +  CAST(@nowQuarter as VARCHAR(3)) 
         +  '.[tVisits]'

-- magic code --
myTable = DoSomething(@aktTableName)   
-- magic code --

SELECT * FROM myTable
```

I use MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL

Comment: Although dynamic SQL does solve your problem, I suspect that a better data structure might help more.  It seems that you have multiple tables with the same columns.  You would be better off having one table `sch` that has yaer and quarter as columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the dynamic SQL -

```
DECLARE 
      @nowYear INT = 2013
    , @nowQuarter INT = 1

DECLARE @myTableName NVARCHAR(100) = '[sch' 
         +  CAST(@nowYear AS VARCHAR(5)) 
         +  'Q' 
         +  CAST(@nowQuarter AS VARCHAR(3)) 
         +  '].[tVisits]'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @myTableName

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT * FROM myTable`

You need to do something like

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * FROM ' + @myTable -- @myTable is a string containing qualified table name
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Note that sp_executesql allows for a parameterized query - check [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)